# limits questions squeeze theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series

Find the limit of:

$a_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt2}+\frac{2}{3}+\frac{3}{\sqrt{28}}+...+\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^3+1}}$

I'm having trouble in figuring out what the upper part of the squeeze theorem could be.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: You can use $ \sum_2^n \frac{1}{n} < a_n < \sum_1^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ for bounds.

Comment: but how do i show the limit of the sum of that as n tends to infinity

Comment: @J.Doe updated.

Comment: The upper series given in the answer diverges, you can prove that by comparing with the [harmonic series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics))

Answer (score 0):

It does not converge, it goes to infinity:

$$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^3+1}}\geq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{k}{\sqrt{k^3+k^3}}\geq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2k}}\geq \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}k}$$
and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics).